# Unit Testing a List<>

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I new to unit testing. I want to unit test a public method which gets the data from sql, and holds it in a LIST<>. So whats the best possible way to do it.
This is my code,

```
public static IList<UserDetails> GetUsersListForAllLocation()
    {
        using (AuthorizationScope authScope = new AuthorizationScope(AdminLogicalResource.Contacts.GetDisplayName(), ApplicationPermission.Update.ToString()))
        {
            var parameters = new[]
            {
                new Simplex.Parameter("@LoggedInUserId", ComponentContext.CurrentCustomer.UserId)
            };

            IList<UserDetails> contactList = ComponentContext.CommonDal.DeserializeMultiRecords<UserDetails>("[CR2].[spGetAllLocationUsers]", parameters, storedProcedure: true);
            return contactList;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is a huge topic, and your question is far too general to give a good answer. Start by reading on the subject and get an understanding of concepts like inversion of control and SOLID design principles.

Answer (score 1):

This code seems tightly coupled to your sql database, hence you likely want an integration test rather than a unit test.

If you want to go with an integration test, you could:

- Set up a test database with known data
- Have this method query this test database when in the test environment
- Assert that the list you retrieve is actually the list you expect

For the assertion, you could use Nunit [CollectionAssert](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=collectionAssert&r=2.4)

Your test could look like

```
[Test]
public void ShouldRetrieveItemsFromDatabase(){
    List<UserDetails> expected = BuildExpectedList();
    List<UserDetails> actual = GetUsersListForAllLocation();
    CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent(expected, actual);
}
```